# Symfony: on response ready event

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

In my project, I've implemented custom i18n class that collects all untranslated strings during the page load. Now, I would like to save them to the message source after the response has been built (hence all strings are collected). What is the right event to hook into?

Comment: Is it like this plugin ? http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/mgI18nPlugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "response.filter_content" event gets fired right before sending the response to the browser. Hope that helps.